# Flutter ObjectBox: Incoming index ID does not match existing UID

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm dealing with an issue related to ObjectBox migrations. Whenever I make a name change to any property in the app, if I re-run the `flutter pub run build_runner build` command to re-build the generated files, I'll get an error like the following if I try to run the app:

```
ObjectBoxException (ObjectBoxException: failed to create store: 10501 Incoming index ID 1:4292904108897114889 does not match existing UID 6540362680558265679)
```

I know from the error message that this is an issue related to one of the indexId values in the objectbox-model.json file. Using github, I can see that running the build_runner command has caused everywhere that uses an indexId value to generate a new value. If I search the IDs listed in the error message, I can confirm that the existing ID in my objectbox-model.json was repleaced by the incoming ID.

I've already ensured that every entity and property in the app is labeled with the appropriate UID values. Because of this, I don't see the normal ID values in objectbox-model.json being replaced with the build_runner command. However, I cannot find any reference online to this incoming index exception. The [ObjectBox Docs Toubleshooting page](https://docs.objectbox.io/troubleshooting#dbschemaexception-incoming-id-does-not-match-existing-uid) does mention this exception, however this refers to the Java version. There is an [explanation on how to use UIDs](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates#uids), but it only covers @Entity and @Property, which I already use. I've also attempted to search online for anyone else who's had this issue, however I can only find questions about incoming ***entity*** IDs, not ***index*** IDs.

I cannot provide an exact copy of my code due to company security policies, however here is a minor example of what the code looks like:

### Class definitions:

```
@Entity(uid: 1111111111111111111)
class ChildType {
  @Property(uid: 2222222222222222222)
  int id = 0;

  @Property(uid: 3333333333333333333)
  final parent = ToOne<ParentType>();

  @Property(uid: 4444444444444444444)
  @Unique(onConflict: ConflictStrategy.replace)
  String childName;

  @Index()
  @Property(uid: 5555555555555555555, type: PropertyType.date)
  DateTime childBirthday;
}

@Entity(uid: 6666666666666666666)
class ParentType {
  @Property(uid: 7777777777777777777)
  int id = 0;

  @Backlink("parent")
  final children = ToMany<ChildType>();

  @Property(uid: 8888888888888888888)
  @Unique(onConflict: ConflictStrategy.replace)
  String parentName;

  @Index()
  @Property(uid: 9999999999999999999, type: PropertyType.date)
  DateTime parentBirthday;
}

@Entity(uid: 0000000000000000000)
class UnrelatedType {
  @Property(uid: 0101010101010101010)
  int id = 0;

  @Property(uid: 9898989898989898989)
  int renamedVar;  <--- renamed, causes database migration, requires build_runner command
}
```

### objectbox-model.json:

```
"entities": [
  {
    "id": "1:1111111111111111111",
    "lastPropertyId": "4:5555555555555555555",
    "name": "ChildType",
    "properties" : [
      {
        "id": "1:2222222222222222222",
        "name": "id",
        "type":6 ,
        "flags" 1 
      },
      {
        "id": "2:3333333333333333333",
        "name": "parentId",
        "type": 11,
        "flags" 520,
        "indexId": "1:1231231231231231231",  <--- changes after build_runner command
        "relationTarget": "ParentType"
      },
      {
        "id": "3:4444444444444444444",
        "name": "childName",
        "type": 9,
        "flags" 34848,
        "indexId": "2:2342342342342342342"  <--- changes after build_runner command
      },
      {
        "id": "4:5555555555555555555",
        "name": "childBirthday",
        "type": 10,
        "flags" 8,
        "indexId": "3:3453453453453453453"  <--- changes after build_runner command
      }
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  {
    "id": "2:6666666666666666666",
    "lastPropertyId": "3:9999999999999999999",
    "name": "ParentType",
    "properties" : [
      {
        "id": "1:7777777777777777777",
        "name": "id",
        "type":6 ,
        "flags" 1 
      },
      {
        "id": "2:8888888888888888888",
        "name": "parentName",
        "type": 9,
        "flags" 34848,
        "indexId": "4:4564564564564564564"  <--- changes after build_runner command
      },
      {
        "id": "3:9999999999999999999",
        "name": "parentBirthday",
        "type": 10,
        "flags" 8,
        "indexId": "5:5675675675675675675"  <--- changes after build_runner command
      }
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  {
    "id": "3:0000000000000000000",
    "lastPropertyId": "2:9898989898989898989",
    "name": "UnrelatedType ",
    "properties" : [
      {
        "id": "1:0101010101010101010",
        "name": "id",
        "type":6 ,
        "flags" 1 
      },
      {
        "id": "2:9898989898989898989",
        "name": "renamedVar",
        "type":6
      }
    ],
    "relations": []
  }
]
```

Comment: You should not choose UIDs yourself, see the instructions at https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates#how-to-and-example which also apply for Flutter/Dart (instead of re-building re-run build_runner).

To resolve the Index UID conflict, see https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/meta-model-ids-and-uids#manual-conflict-resolution

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox I did not choose the UIDs myself. The UIDs used here are fake UIDs to obfuscate confidential code. I set the UIDs by letting the objectbox-model.json file generate them first, then copying them into the UID parameter of the Property tags. And looking at the page you've linked here, I'm not sure I understand how to properly handle index UID conflicts. The issue isn't that different developers are setting different index UIDs, the issue is that a single developer running build_runner can cause the index UIDs to be regenerated and cause conflicts.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this, but failed to do so. The code that handles this also looks OK. Could you submit an issue at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues with an example that can be used to reproduce?